# How to change WildFly version in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, wildfly

I have to edit a project where the WildFly version is an old one. The project was exported with all configurations.

In Eclipse you can change this WildFly version under project settings but I wanted to use IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new server version at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Application Servers.

Then [edit the run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) to update the server used.

You may also check if the server is used as a [provided module dependency](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency) and update it there as well.